# Were the known laws of physics valid at the Big Bang?

Tags: big-bang

Did the currently known laws of physics also come into existence at the time of the big bang? What about the various constants such as mass of electron or speed of light? Did these also come into existence or are they part of the novelty of the big bang itself.

Comment: Nobody knows; one can build various models. If one assumes our current laws, and winds the clock backwards, eventually there is a breakdown.  For example, see the book "The First Three Minutes", by Steven Weinberg.

Comment: Based on observational data they were valid a very short time after the big bang (if you want to restrict that term to a single moment in time, which is not even particularly useful). The question is not so much if these laws were valid as it's more of a question what these laws actually look like at high energies and densities. The latter we don't know, yet, but we are trying very hard to find out. That's what LHC is doing, among other things.

Comment: good_ole_ray: are you really interested by "exactly at the BB" (assuming this means something) or "very soon after" (and then how soon) ?. And what is your interest behind the question (what it is for): high curvature of the space ? high density and temperature ? something else ?

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET just interested if the laws of physics were also a novelty. i guess whatever we say is pure speculation

Comment: Yes (well, to some amount it's depend on the very question), but first, whatever we say has to be a well-posed question (or it's not even false or true ;-) )

Comment: Like what you exactly mean "a novelty". For instance at early stages the universe was hugely curved, and most of the law you know for Earth condition assume Euclidian space (i.e. flat).  But most can easily be adapted to non-Euclidian spaces. Same for all topology and differential issues. Also if there are not yet atoms can you really say that chemistery is "not yet true" ?